# I have an issue when connecting to scardsyn.dll from c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

When I try to run the following code :

```
[DllImport("scardsyn.dll")] 
public static int SCardCLGetUID(int ulHandleCard, byte[] pucUID, int ulUIDBufLen, ref int pulnByteUID);
```

I get the following error :

```
'Star.ModWinsCard.SCardCLGetUID(int, byte[], int, ref int)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
```

any helps whould be appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the message, you have to mark your method as [extern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
[DllImport("scardsyn.dll")] 
public static extern int SCardCLGetUID(int ulHandleCard, byte[] pucUID, int ulUIDBufLen, ref int pulnByteUID);
```